# How to browse var/log directories in console app as could be done in OS versions prior to Catalina?

Tags: catalina, bug, logs, console

In Mac OS prior to Catalina, the left sidebar in the console app would show a directory tree for the `/var/log` directory and a few other log directories. These could be expanded to navigate logs for various processes. I am pretty sure at least one, `/var/log`, was there by default.

Now, there doesn't appear to be a way to get any log directories to show in the sidebar—even by opening through the file menu or by drag/dropping. It only shows the default:

- Devices

  - [Device name]
- Reports

  - Crash Reports
  - Spin Reports
  - Log Reports
  - Diagnostic Reports
  - Mac Analytics Data
  - system.log

These are the same sidebar items that were present in previous versions, minus the directories.

I can open up individual log files with the console, but cannot get any directories to show up in the sidebar.

Maybe this is a regression and wasn't intentionally removed.

How can I get log directories to show up permanently like in the previous OS?